# R arules freezes depending on data format

Tags: r, arules

I am facing aproblem with arules package in R.
I am trying to carry out market basket analysis on a supermarket dataset.
If I use data in the format:

```
item1;item2;item3;item4;item5;item6;item7;item8;item9
art-9;art-123;art-260;art-305;art-1099;art-1512;art-1588;art-1768;art-2080
art-8;art-147;art-257;art-426;art-1167;art-1504;art-1579;art-1883;art-2006
```

everything works fine, even loading hundreds of thousands of rows :) ... 
but I need to load data in the following format:

```
art-1;art-2;art-3;art-4;art-5;art-6;art-7;
F;F;T;F;F;F;T
F;F;F;F;F;F;F
```

the system freezes even when loading only 250 rows...
Could data in this format used with arules?

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any problem with your data set

```
library(arules)

dd1 = read.table(textConnection("item1;item2;item3;item4;item5;item6;item7;item8;item9
art-9;art-123;art-260;art-305;art-1099;art-1512;art-1588;art-1768;art-2080
art-8;art-147;art-257;art-426;art-1167;art-1504;art-1579;art-1883;art-2006"),
                sep=";")


trans = as(dd1, "transactions")
apriori(trans)

dd2 = read.table(textConnection("art-1;art-2;art-3;art-4;art-5;art-6;art-7
F;F;T;F;F;F;T
F;F;F;F;F;F;F"), sep=";")
trans = as(dd2, "transactions")
apriori(trans)
```